# Java - downloaded ZIP archive from S3 is corrupted

Tags: java, amazon-s3, zip

I'm trying to download a ZIP archive from a S3 bucket, using this code:

```
S3Object fullObject = client.getObject(bucketName, key);
S3ObjectInputStream stream = fullObject.getObjectContent();

FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(archiveName);

while ((count = stream.read(data)) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(data, 0, count);
}

outputStream.close();
stream.close();
```

The file gets downloaded, it has about the same size as the one placed in S3, the only problem is that it's corrupted. If I type `unzip -t <archive_name.zip>`, I get the following error:

`End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of PCxazGHgMmDedx8wNM16L.zip or
        PCxazGHgMmDedx8wNM16L.zip.zip, and cannot find PCxazGHgMmDedx8wNM16L.zip.ZIP, period.`

I tried to use a `ZipOutputStream` declared like that:

`ZipOutputStream zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream));`

but it requires a ZipEntry, which is basically a new file / directory inside the archive that I can't see because I only got a stream.

How can I solve this issue?

Thank you respectfully.

Comment: have you been able to verify that the original zipfile is (or isn't) corrupted?

Comment: Yes, if I download the original zip file manually it's perfectly fine

Comment: Also, if I want to unzip it by double clicking on it, (in Finder), it works

Comment: You might check the objects metadata if they look valid for this object `objectMetadata.getRawMetadata()`.

Comment: It could also be, that the file is not a ZIP file and maybe a Gzip file. This could be revealed in the metadata.

Comment: I understand. I will check it out

Comment: Could you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, I was mistakenly building the ZIP archive using TarEntries. It was correctly managed by the Finder (it somehow handles this situation). Now it works. Thanks!